# load a file from the memory

Tags: c++, file

I have a image file encrypted. now my program will read the encrypted file and create the image in a char array. now my problem is i need to open the image with some image viewer without writing the image file to the hard disc. it should be possible because the image data is already loaded in the ram.

Comment: `it should be possible because the image data is already loaded in the ram.` That's a bold claim. Memory is not one big free-for-all -- memory owned by one process is usually _quite deliberately_ not accessible from another. You'd have to write an image viewer that is designed specifically to interface with your read program. Hard disks solve this problem.

Comment: do you code the viewer yourselfe?

Comment: no I need to pass a data address or something to the default jpg viewer of the pc

Comment: There is no "ram" in C++...

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible, not "image viewer" takes a data address as a parameter to load some arbitrary data, it's not even allowed by the OS (at least, most OSes I know of)

Comment: then is it possible to open that memory block as a new drive. I have seen such softwear.

Comment: You can't even be sure your image is actually *in* physical memory - the OS might already have written it to disk for you.

Comment: People never seem to understand the basic concept that it will never be possible to disclose data and at the same time keep it private on any general purpose operating system.  Sure go through the motions on this -- you make it harder for the average person to access the data, and history has shown that this will accordingly limit the number of customers willing to use the product, but I also understand that this is probably something someone is paying you to attempt, and business people are notoriously idiotic in their belief that putting their customers through DRM hoops is a good idea.

Comment: @gview nope. this is for educational purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any image viewer that is able to load images from memory regions. Even if you would create your own image viewer, you'd have to share the memory region or the viewer most probably won't be able to access your programs memory for security reasons.

A compromise would be to write the image to a temporary directory on the hard disk, open it with the image viewer and overwriting it with random data and deleting the file after use (for small files you even can delete it after the image viewer finished loading).

From what you're writing, it seems that you want to avoid writing the decrypted data to the hard disk, which is fine because data written to the hard disk will still be there after a shutdown, while data in RAM won't survive. But as JasonD pointed out in his comment, this can lead to a false sense of security - the OS is free to move memory regions into virtual memory (and so to the hard disk) at any time.

EDIT: Opening a memory region might be possible, e.g. you can try out the [hex editor HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) - it can open and edit memory regions allocated by processes, although I don't know how it does it.

Comment: thanks for your advice. is it possible to open my memory block as a new drive

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by others, the fact that the data is present in memory gives you nothing unless the image viewer supports loading images via interprocess communication mechanisms (and I have yet to see such viewer).

So your options are to use some image viewing library for C++ (which can be a perfect option, BTW) or create a virtual disk.

Regarding memory swapped to disk - you can mark memory as unswappable, but you need to ensure that such memory block can be allocated (for large images this would be not possible).

You can create a virtual disk which will expose the data stored in RAM but you need a kernel-mode virtual disk driver for this. This requires solid experience in kernel-mode development though. Our company offers several products (SolFS OS edition, CallbackDisk) which you can use for your task and get an encrypted in-memory storage with almost no programming.

Answer (score 0):

There is just one way to do it and it's abslutly not the easy one! You need a filter dirver to link a virtaul file system into userspace. You can have a look at the "dokan"-project to get more information.

If this is a comercial project, you should be very familia with NTFS drivers, because I think, dokan isn't supported.

I used it and it is working fine, but it took me about three months to get into this stuff.

If it's not a "high security app", you can use temporary files.